# dar uma borda a um objecto que não existe

Tags: html, css

Olá!

Eu gostaria de colocar uma borda no meu contador. O problema é que o meu contador baseia-se no números de casos do json, então os números no html não existem.

Existe alguma forma de dar uma borda na div que não tem conteúdo?

```js
document.getElementById("contadorprincipal").innerHTML = arrayResultados.length;
```

```css
.contadorprincipalcapa {
    color: white;
    font-size: 15px;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="contadorprincipalcapa">
    <div id="contadorprincipal"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Você precisa adicionar um conteúdo, um padding ou definir um tamanho fixo/mínimo para a div

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisa adicionar um conteúdo, um padding ou definir um tamanho fixo/mínimo para a div. Neste caso adicionei um `height` mínimo:

```js
document.getElementById("contadorprincipal").innerHTML = "50" //arrayResultados.length;
```

```css
.contadorprincipalcapa {
    color: white;
    font-size: 15px;
    margin: 10px;
    min-height: 1em; /* 2em = 2 vezes o tamanho da fonte */
    border: 1px solid #000;
    background: #000
}
```

```html
<div class="contadorprincipalcapa">
    <div id="contadorprincipal"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: funcionou assim que der para dar o certo eu marco como correto